# Is convergence in probability to a uniformly continuous function a sufficient condition for stochastic equicontinuity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, continuity, uniform-continuity

Suppose that a random function $g_T(\theta)$ converges in probability to a function $g(\theta)$ uniformly continuous over $\Theta$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$ $\forall \theta \in \Theta$. Is this condition sufficient for stochastic equicontinuity of the sequence of empirical processes $\{g_T(\cdot); T\geq 1\} $?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Have you considered what happens if you take $\Theta = [0,1]$ (which is compact) and $g_T$ to be continuous, non-random, uniformly bounded and pointwise convergent to a continuous function, but not uniformly convergent?

Comment: I see that it is not sufficient. Are you also suggesting that if instead $g_T(\theta)$ uniformly converges in probability to a function $g(\theta)$ uniformly continuous over $\Theta$, then this would be sufficient for stochastic equicontinuity? Could you provide in case a sketch of the proof?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can reduce this to a functional analysis problem. I would have to write this out to be sure but I think it follows immediately from the fact that $X_n \stackrel{\tiny{p}}{\to} X$ if and only if every subsequence of $X_n$ has a further subsequence which converges to $X$ almost surely.  With this, you can exchange uniform convergence in probability for almost sure uniform convergence.  I cannot remember under what exact circumstances uniform convergence implies equicontinuity; I think that without compactness of $\Theta$, it may not be possible to say anything.

Comment: If $\Theta$ is a compact Hausdorff space and you have uniform convergence in probability, this should follow from the Arzela-Ascoli theorem though.